# Why are diodes able to amplify signals in groups, but not alone?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, molecules

Single diodes can determine whether a signal passes or not (depending on the biased)(plus they can even rectify a signal), yet why does it take a combination of diodes(like a transistor) to amplify a signal?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Arguable, because this is about device physics.

Comment: Have you forgotten the field-effect transistor?  The FET (1) contains one PN junction and (2) is a 3-terminal device which (3) can be configured as an amplifier.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/fet.html

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Nice cutoff! I thought this was heading toward "The Ebers-Moll equation describes the current in a PN junction using parameters you can never get from a semiconductor manufacturer......"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A transistor is not simply a combination of diodes.

A bipolar junction transistor is a complex device consisting of three layers of differently doped semiconductor.

If a current is pumped through the base-emitter juction, there will be several times greater collector-emitter current because of the increased amount of minority carriers in the base region.

[See Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

Comment: ... and those extra carriers are there because the forward-biased emitter-base junction loaded them there.  The device has to be small to prevent those carriers from recombining.  That's why two diodes wired together won't work.